# List Index Out of Range Error : Python

Tags: python, proxy, network-programming

I am working on a programming exercise from Computer Networking: A Top-Down Approach (6th Edition) by Kurose and Ross)

When I run the server code and type localhost:1234/www.facebook.com in my browser I face List Index Out of Range Error.

> Error : 
>   Received a connection from: ('127.0.0.1', 15376)
>
> Message:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "Manu.py", line 17, in  print message.split()[1]
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

**Code**:

```
from socket import socket
import sys

if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
    print('Usage: "python ProxyServer.py server_ip\n'
          'server_ip: It is the IP Address of the Proxy Server')
    sys.exit(2)

# Create a server socket, bind it to a port and start listening
tcpSerPort = 1234
tcpSerSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

# Prepare a server socket
tcpSerSock.bind(('', tcpSerPort))
tcpSerSock.listen(5)

while True:
    # Start receiving data from the client
    print 'Ready to serve...'
    tcpCliSock, addr = tcpSerSock.accept()
    print 'Received a connection from: ', addr
    message = tcpCliSock.recv(1024)

    # Extract the filename from the given message
    print message.split()[1]
    filename = message.split()[1].partition("/")[2]
    fileExist = "false"
    filetouse = "/" + filename
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the likely culprits which assume something was returned:

```
print message.split()[1]
filename = message.split()[1].partition("/")[2]
```

Try:

```
m = message.split()
if m:
    print(m[1])
    filename = m[1].partition("/")[2]
```

Also, it is best not to use "/" when joining files as it is platform specific.  A more pythonic way would be to use `join`:

```
import os
file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is creating error as you are accessing element from list which don't have any element. Try below code where you check if you get elements in message.

```
if len(message.split())> 0:
    print message.split()[1]
```